# SSAS adomd-client with mutual SSL

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssas

I configured a local SSAS-server with IIS and mututal SSL.

Connection via Browser to https://127.0.0.1/OLAP/msmdpump.dll works fine with client-cert.

But I seems, that tool like

- Excel
- Tableau
- Power BI
- SQL Server Management Studio

can provide a client certificate connecting to the server.

So i tried the most "raw" approach: a little .net-core7-project with `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64/19.55.3.1`

```
AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection("DataSource=https://127.0.0.1/OLAP/msmdpump.dll;Catalog=Analysis Services Tutorial"))
conn.Open();
```

effect

```
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.HttpChannelController.GetResponseMessageImpl(HttpStream owner, Object context, Task`1 pendingResponse)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.HttpChannelController.CompleteHttpClientBasedOperation(HttpStream owner, Object context, Task`1 pendingResponse)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.HttpXmlaOperation.HttpClientOperationManager.GetResponse(HttpXmlaOperation operation)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.LegacyController.HttpClientXmlaOperation.GetResponseImpl()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.HttpXmlaOperation.EnsureCanRead()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.LegacyController.LegacyXmlaOperation.EnsureCanRead()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.HttpXmlaOperation.GetResponseDataType()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.GetResponseDataType()
```

At that point I don't see any approach to manipulate the `httpSteam`/`httpClient`, so I can add a client certificate to be used in the connection.

Any ideas or any example of a working `MutualSSL<->SSAS`-Configuration?

Comment: I've never heard of anyone using client certificates to connect to analysis services.  What are you trying to acomplish?

Comment: simple: increase security.

Comment: Why not just use Kerberos?

Comment: we need something more "web-native" in that case like MutSSL, OAUTH2 (OpenId) or SAML.
I expected that this should be (easily) possible as SSAS via IIS relies on a https-communication.

Answer (score 0):

SSAS clients support NTLM, Kerberos, and (only with the data pump) HTTP Basic auth.  They also support Azure Active Directory auth when connecting to Azure Analysis Services and Power BI, but not SSAS.  There are XMLA protocol differences between the AAS/PBI and SSAS.

So the only real extensibility point would be to have the client use HTTP Basic and pass something other than a Windows Username/Password to some sort of HTTP proxy.

Here's an old sample that does that: [SSASProxy Custom HTTP Security Sample](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-community-s-z/tree/master/SSASProxy%20Custom%20HTTP%20Security%20Sample)

Comment: Thank you, David!
I think, your solution works the "other way round", but it inspired  me, to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a workaround by introducing apache httpd as reverse proxy:

assume your IIS is configured on `https://127.0.0.1:443/`, then following `modproxy`-config should do the trick:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:28447>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine on
  ServerName 127.0.0.1:28447
  SSLCertificateFile "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyCa\proxyServer\proxyServer.pem"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyCa\proxyServer\proxyServer_private.pem"
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:443/
  ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:443/
  #SSLProxyMachineCertificateChainFile "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyCa\Root\CaPub.pem"
  SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyCa\client1\client1_private_key.pem"
  
  DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
# DocumentRoot access handled globally in httpd.conf
    CustomLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
        Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit FileInfo
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</virtualhost>
```

Now you can

```
 Invoke-WebRequest https://localhost:28447/OLAP/msmdpump.dll
```

without a client-cert because apache coats your request with `client1_private_key.pem`.

Comment: Ok.  What sort of authentication is the client going to present to your reverse proxy?

Comment: I can put the reverse-proxy-installation to the same network-zone, where the client (Tabluea-Server, Excel) resides  (or even on the same machine in edgecases). 
From that point the communication to the remote OLAP-Server (e.g. www) is secured with MSSL.
This increases the security of the OLAP-Server, because in fact it can't be accessed without a valid client cert.
And yes: I would still wish, that the OLAPclient(s) could do MSSL outOfTheBox - this would provide the best security.